# What causes `WARNING in ./node_modules/<package> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js): Failed to parse source map

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5

I am not interested in finding out how to get rid of this problem. I already found multiple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195843/webpack-module-warning-failed-to-parse-source-map-from-data-url). What I want to know since this issue is coming from my own package is how can I present this error/warning from happening in the first place.

As the original package owner what can I do to present this warning from being generated.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/package-system/utilities/lib/Constants.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/roger_perez/Sites/DemoShop/node_modules/package-system/utilities/src/Constants.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/roger_perez/Sites/DemoShop/node_modules/package-system/utilities/src/Constants.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/package-system/utilities/lib/index.js 2:0-37 2:0-37
 @ ./node_modules/package-system/components/lib/utils/index.js 1:0-51 1:0-51
 @ ./node_modules/package-system/components/lib/index.js 19:0-24 19:0-24
 @ ./src/App.tsx 4:0-68 18:39-54
 @ ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24 17:50-53
```

[image: failed to parse source map from image]

Answer (score 0):

Add in `.env`

```js
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

or add in `package.json`

```
"start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",
```