# How to ignore React webpack warnings about dependency source maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, warnings, silent

Using a create-react-app setup (i.e. there is no Webpack configuration file in project code) with react-scripts 5.0.1 (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975849/798371)) and adding dependencies, on every build of my app (including dev-server builds from saving app files) I see lots of warnings from Webpack of the following form:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/myDependency/index.js
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Failed to parse source map from 'path\to\project\node_modules\myDependency\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path\to\project\node_modules\myDependency\index.ts'

(This is running on Windows, as an explanation for the funky slash directions there.)

In response to other questions, answers generally recommend adding a `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` flag, which disables source maps altogether, and they are useful.  I would like to continue generating sourcemaps especially for project code, but silence warnings about the lack of source maps in dependencies (i.e. those under `/node_modules/`).

How do I do that?

While these extra warnings do not prevent the app from working, they may be burying other warnings that are more important and actionable.