# Webpack Failed To Compile Error, when I was trying to compile a react app

Tags: reactjs

Failed to parse source map: 'webpack:///../../src/chains/index.ts' URL is not supported

Failed to parse source map: 'webpack:///../../src/eips/index.ts' URL is not supported

Failed to parse source map: 'webpack:///../../src/hardforks/index.ts' URL is not supported

Failed to parse source map: 'webpack:///../src.ts/_version.ts' URL is not supported

Failed to parse source map: 'webpack:///../src.ts/abi-coder.ts' URL is not supported

Failed to parse source map: 'webpack:///../src.ts/addresses.ts' URL is not supported

Failed to parse source map: 'webpack:///../src.ts/bignumber.ts' URL is not supported

I loaded my react project an kept on getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note This is from this stackoverflow question: [Webpack Module Warning: Failed to parse source map from "data" URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195843/webpack-module-warning-failed-to-parse-source-map-from-data-url)

if you're experiencing this issue with react-scripts/cra version 5.0.0. You'll need to add the following to your .env file

NOTE: this is not a fix. You are suppressing the source map warnings, but it may get you from seeing those warnings since all other solutions have not worked.

GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

or you can update your script to

`"start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",`

Note: this is a temporary patch until 5.0.1 is released. See create-react-app repo pull request Update: 5.0.1 was release on April 2022. [Changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md). The update did not fix this issue. Not sure when that will be ‍♂️